# jQuery .blur() not working on dynamically generated fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a login form, that has registration form also. The email field is dynamically generated with jQuery.

I have the labels below the fields, so I can position them inside the field. And when the field is on focus, or it has content in it, the label moves above the field.

But, all this is working on the username and password but not on email. Not sure why.

Here's the codepen:

http://codepen.io/andornagy/pen/waoyZB

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    var inp = $('#emailhere');
    var i = 0;
    var emailField = $('<section class="emailc"><input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="field"><label for="email" class="email">E-mail</label></section');

    // Do stuff when you click to show register form
    $('ul.tabs li.register').click(function(){

        $('#do').val('register');

        $('.button').val('Register');

        if ( i < 1 ) {

            $('#emailhere').after(emailField);

        };

    });

    // Do stuff when you click to show login form
    $('ul.tabs li.login').click(function(){

        $('.emailc').remove();

        var i = 0;

        $('#do').val('login');

        $('.button').val('Login');

    }); 

    // Moving the input labels correctly.
    $('#login').on("blur", "input",function() {

        // Make the label stay above if the field is not empty.
        if( this.value ) {
            $(this).next().addClass('notEmpty');
        }

        // Make the label go back on the field if the field is empty.
        if( !this.value ) {
            $(this).next().removeClass('notEmpty');
        }

    });

});
```

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab);

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #4A5043;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

.clear:after {
    display: block;
    content:" ";
    clear: both;
}

/* The Base container styles
===================================*/

.tabs {
    display: block;
    margin: -25px -25px 40px -25px;
    padding: 0;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
}

.tabs li {
    display: block;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 15px 25px 19px 25px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center;
}

.tabs .login {
    border-right: 1px solid #FFFFF;
}

#form {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 150px auto;
    background-color: #5C505A;
    padding: 25px;
}

#form .field {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 14px;
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
}

#form .button:focus,
#form .field:focus {
    outline: none;
    border-color:; #000000;
}

#form .field + label {
    position: relative;
    bottom:42px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #5C505A;
    z-index: 999;
}

#form .field + .notEmpty,
#form .field:focus + label {
    bottom: 88px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#form label:focus + label {
    bottom: 0;
    color: #5C505A;
}

#form .button,
#form .button:hover,
#form .field + label,
#form .field:focus + label {
    transition: 0.5s bottom,
                0.5s color,
                0.5s border-color,
                0.5s background-color;
}

#form .button {
    display: block;
    width: 294px;
    padding: 10px;
    font-size: 22px;
    border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
    background:none;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#form .button:hover {
    color: #5C505A;
    background:#FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<!-- #form container -->
<section id="form">

    <ul class="tabs clear">
        <li class="login">Login</li>
        <li class="register">Register</li>
    </ul>
    <!-- #login container -->
    <section id="login">

        <!-- Login form -->
        <form name="login" action="#">

            <!-- Username field -->
            <p>
            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="field">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
</p>
            <div id="emailhere"></div>

            <!-- Password field -->
            <input type="password" name="password"id="password" class="field">
            <label for="password">Password</label>

            <!-- hidden value for validation -->
            <input type="hidden" id="do" name="do" value="login">       

            <!-- submit button -->
            <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Login">

        </form><!-- /ends Login form -->

    </section><!-- #login ends -->

    <!-- #register container -->
    <section id="register">

    </section><!-- #register ends -->

</section><!-- #form ends -->
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't do it cuz there's too much code.

Comment: True, sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at you code, try ...

```
$('#login').on("blur", "input", function() {
```

... instead of ...

```
$('#login input').blur(function() {
```

Your issue is most likely that the dynamic field does not exist when your code put the blur in place ... since `#login` exists, the input can be located when it is dynamically added.

So, looking at the `on` function, it is run against `#login` which is not dynamic and the `blur` is matched against ANY `input` tags whether they existed before or were added after the command is run.  Basically, it's like using jQuery's `find` looking for `inputs`.

This way, the code is "attached" to the `#login`, but watching for any `input` tags, irregardless of when they are created.